# В данной программе надо уменьшить или изменить блок кода bool try_hod

Tags: c++

```
    //В этой программе конь из шахматной игры должен пройти по всем клеточкам на доске.
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
bool map[8][8];// true - свободная ячейка, [y][x], y - снизу вверх
int hody[64];//число клеток на поле
long long total_count = 0;// счетчик количества попыток
bool try_hod(int y, int x, int filled);

bool check(int try_y, int try_x, int filled) {//функция проверки которая возвращает значение был ли конь в клетке или нет.
    if (try_y >= 0 && try_y <= 7 && try_x >= 0 && try_x <= 7) {//если да то она отправляет его в другую клетку.
        if (map[try_y][try_x]) {// если нет то отмечает ее.
            if (try_hod(try_y, try_x, filled)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

__bool try_hod(int y, int x, int filled) {
    total_count++;
    if (total_count % 1000000 == 0);
    map[y][x] = false; // заняли клетку
    filled++;
    
    if (filled == 64) {// прописываем запонение клеток.
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    // 8 вариантов хода, если успешно, то 
    //  hody[zanyato - 1] = x + y * 8;
    //  return true;
    
    if (check(y + 1, x - 2, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y + 2, x - 1, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y + 2, x + 1, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y + 1, x + 2, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y - 1, x + 2, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y - 2, x + 1, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y - 2, x - 1, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
    else if (check(y - 1, x - 2, filled))
    {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }

    map[y][x] = true; // освободили клетку
    return false;__
}

void step (short x, short y) {//стартовая точка 
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), { x,y });
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            map[i][j] = true;//создание поля
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
        hody[j] = -1;// создание коня
    cout << try_hod(0, 0, 0) << endl;
    int x, y;//установка коня в стартовую позицию и запуск.
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        y = 20 - hody[i] / 8;
        x = hody[i] % 8 * 2 + 40;
        step(x, y);
        Sleep(200);
        cout << ".";
        step(x, y);
        Sleep(300);
        cout << "[]";
        step(x, y);
        Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: В чём проблема? Что программа должна делать? Почему вы решили, что надо что-то менять? Кнопка править под вопросом

Comment: В этой программе конь из шахматной игры должен пройти по всем клеточкам на доске. Меня напрягает тот момент что Функция  bool try_hod получилась слишком объемной и я бы хотел ее уменьшить.

Comment: Повторяю: используйте кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1158841/edit)

Comment: Когда вы на неё нажимаете, вы попадаете в окно редактора вопроса, которое у вас уже было при задании вопроса. В этом окне вы можете изменить текст вопроса. Я предлагаю добавить описание и проблему, которую вы привели в комментарии, в сам вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заменить 8 явных проверок на следующий цикл:

```
std::pair<int, int> deltas[] = {{+1, -2}, {+2, -1}, 
                                {+2, +1}, {+1, +2},
                                {-1, +2}, {-2, +1},
                                {-2, -1}, {-1, -2}};

for (auto[delta_y, delta_x] : deltas) {
    if (check(y + delta_y, x + delta_x, filled)) {
        hody[filled - 1] = x + y * 8;
        return true;
    }
}
```